# How do I change floatingFilter option after Init of AGGrid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using AgGrid with JavaScript module. I'm trying to change the value of floatingFilter after init of Grid by calling api.refreshHeader method but it's not working.

```
function getServices() {
    var columnDefs = [
        { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name' },
        { field: 'Category', headerName: 'Category' },
    ];

    var gridOptions = {
        animateRows: true,
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        defaultColDef: {
            resizable: true,
            filter: true,
            sortable: true,
            flex: 1,
        },
        floatingFilter: true, // I want to change this after init
    };

    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#serviceGrid');
    var gridInstance = new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:"JSON",
        url: 'FROM_URL',
        success:function(data){
            gridOptions.api.setRowData(data)
        }
    });

    // For testing purpose I'm using timeout
    setTimeout(function() {
        gridInstance.gridOptions.floatingFilter = false;
        gridInstance.gridOptions.api.refreshHeader();
    }, 5000)
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which version you are using, but in the latest version, `floatingFilters` go inside `columnDefinitions` and not inside `gridOptions`.

Move `floatingFilters` inside `defaultColDef` in your `gridOptions`.

```
    var gridOptions = {
    animateRows: true,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    defaultColDef: {
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
        sortable: true,
        flex: 1,
        floatingFilter: true, // I want to change this after init
    },
};
```

and then change your setTimeout function to this.

```
// For testing purpose I'm using timeout
setTimeout(function() {
    gridInstance.gridOptions.defaultColDef.floatingFilter = false;
    gridInstance.gridOptions.api.refreshHeader();
}, 5000)
```

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LLFw5k61eYUcXEbX) I forked from one of their examples that works.

Hope I was able to help.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. I'm using version v23.1.0. Let change my mistake.